# How to Target FireFox CSS

Tags: html, css

**Problem:** I am having issues to target FireFox and IE css styling.

The following is what I am doing trying to target FF:

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .centerSpinner{
        top:300% !important;
    }
}
```

However, it does not push the spinner to the center:
[image]

In Chrome, the loading and the spinner are at the center of the page. Here is the full css:

```css
 #floatingCirclesG{
 position:relative;
 width:125px;
 height:125px;
 margin:auto;
 transform:scale(0.6);
  -o-transform:scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform:scale(0.6);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform:scale(0.6);
 }

 .f_circleG{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  height:22px;
  width:22px;
  border-radius:12px;
   -o-border-radius:12px;
   -ms-border-radius:12px;
   -webkit-border-radius:12px;
   -moz-border-radius:12px;
  animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -o-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -ms-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -webkit-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -moz-animation-name:f_fadeG;
  animation-duration:1.2s;
   -o-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -ms-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -webkit-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -moz-animation-duration:1.2s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:normal;
   -o-animation-direction:normal;
   -ms-animation-direction:normal;
   -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
   -moz-animation-direction:normal;
 }

 #frotateG_01{
  left:0;
  top:51px;
  animation-delay:0.45s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.45s;
 }

 #frotateG_02{
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  animation-delay:0.6s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
 }

 #frotateG_03{
  left:51px;
  top:0;
  animation-delay:0.75s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.75s;
 }

 #frotateG_04{
  right:15px;
  top:15px;
  animation-delay:0.9s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
 }

 #frotateG_05{
  right:0;
  top:51px;
  animation-delay:1.05s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.05s;
 }

 #frotateG_06{
  right:15px;
  bottom:15px;
  animation-delay:1.2s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
 }

 #frotateG_07{
  left:51px;
  bottom:0;
  animation-delay:1.35s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.35s;
 }

 #frotateG_08{
  left:15px;
  bottom:15px;
  animation-delay:1.5s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.5s;
 }



 @keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-o-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-ms-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-moz-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }
 
 @-moz-document url-prefix(){
  .centerSpinner{
   top:300% !important;
  }
 }
 
 .background{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 }
 
 .centerSpinner{
  position:relative; top:35%;
 }
 
 .loadCSS{text-align:center; top:100%; position:relative; font-size:37pt !important; right:15%;}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <div class="centerSpinner" id="floatingCirclesG">
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"></div>
   <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"></div>
   <div class="loadCSS">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: They drop the prefix when it's their standard.

Comment: @PHPglue how would I target all FF?

Comment: your target works fine, test color:red; for instance.  if you use a heavier selector, then the it should work better : #floatingCirclesG , and finally top:35vh will do .... to find out tat should work for most of the browser and filtering FF becomes unnecessary ;)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJqJLP

Comment: Use both `-moz-` and without the prefix, like `transform:`

Comment: @GCyrillus: I understand that but it does not work for firefox

Comment: @PHPglue: Still does not work

Comment: which firefox do you use ? this is my main browser and works fine whit me, i build the codepen using firefox :)

Comment: else if it is about centering this in a single page, you have display on HTML (table/flex + height:100%) or html height:100% + inline-block element to vertically center your loader. (inline-block technic worked in IE5.5 ...)

Comment: Current version of FF I am using. 44.something version

Comment: Your snippet breaks in any of my browsers anyway , not just FF

Comment: and your filter works : try : `@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .centerSpinner{
       color:red;
    }
}`

Comment: @GCyrillus: Thanks for letting me know it also breaks in other browsers and it works when I do that but when I do top:35%; does not move the spinner

Comment: it won't do anything, cause your box has no height (content is in absolute too) so 35% from 0 height is still 0

Answer (score 0):

here a few ways to center your box without absolute nor transform:

- flex

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
}
body {
  margin:auto;
}
 /* add your css spinner here */
```

```html
    <div>body content at center <br/> to replace with your spinner</div>
```

- table/table-cell **CSS**

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
  }
body {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
div {
  border:solid;
  display:inline-block;
  }

 /* add your css spinner here */
```

```html
    <div>body content at center <br/> to replace with your spinner</div>
```

- inline-block (old browsers)

```css
html, body , body:before {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  }
body:before {/* or for very old browser a real tag in case your target also IE5 to IE7*/
  content:'';
  }
body:before, div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }

 /* add your css spinner here */
```

```html
    <div>body content at center <br/> to replace with your spinner</div>
```

Comment: @ GCyrillus: I have tried all these approaches and yet it does not show any differences in FF or IE'

Comment: @RobertoFlores maybe it is time to setup a snippet and a fiddle/codepen that shows live your issue , if your snippet in your question indeed breaks in my FF, It also breaks in my  Chrome, Opera and IE ...

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #floatingCirclesG{
  position:absolute;
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  margin-top: -62px;
        margin-left: -62px; 
  top:50%;
        left: 50%;
  transform:scale(0.6);
  -o-transform:scale(0.6);
  -ms-transform:scale(0.6);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform:scale(0.6);
 }

 .f_circleG{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  height:22px;
  width:22px;
  border-radius:12px;
   -o-border-radius:12px;
   -ms-border-radius:12px;
   -webkit-border-radius:12px;
   -moz-border-radius:12px;
  animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -o-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -ms-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -webkit-animation-name:f_fadeG;
   -moz-animation-name:f_fadeG;
  animation-duration:1.2s;
   -o-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -ms-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -webkit-animation-duration:1.2s;
   -moz-animation-duration:1.2s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:normal;
   -o-animation-direction:normal;
   -ms-animation-direction:normal;
   -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
   -moz-animation-direction:normal;
 }

 #frotateG_01{
  left:0;
  top:51px;
  animation-delay:0.45s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.45s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.45s;
 }

 #frotateG_02{
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  animation-delay:0.6s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
 }

 #frotateG_03{
  left:51px;
  top:0;
  animation-delay:0.75s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.75s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.75s;
 }

 #frotateG_04{
  right:15px;
  top:15px;
  animation-delay:0.9s;
   -o-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -ms-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
 }

 #frotateG_05{
  right:0;
  top:51px;
  animation-delay:1.05s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.05s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.05s;
 }

 #frotateG_06{
  right:15px;
  bottom:15px;
  animation-delay:1.2s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
 }

 #frotateG_07{
  left:51px;
  bottom:0;
  animation-delay:1.35s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.35s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.35s;
 }

 #frotateG_08{
  left:15px;
  bottom:15px;
  animation-delay:1.5s;
   -o-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -ms-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1.5s;
 }



 @keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-o-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-ms-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-moz-keyframes f_fadeG{
  0%{
   background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  100%{
   background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
  }
 }

 @-moz-document url-prefix(){ .centerSpinner{ color:red; top:500px; } }
 
 .background{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 }
 
 .centerSpinner{top:35%;}

 .loadCSS{text-align:center; top:100%; position:relative; font-size:37pt !important; right:15%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Useless</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body class="background">
    <div>
        <!-- This div will be centered -->
    </div>
    <div class="centerSpinner" id="floatingCirclesG">
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"></div>
        <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"></div>
        <div class="loadCSS">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my updated answer. So your problem is that the div holding the spinner was positioned relative to the body, and you body was only a few hundred pixels tall. Now if you position your div absolute (meaning you remove the div from its natural flow in the DOM), in this case, it will be absolute positioned to the browser. (This might change if you have a parent position relative, so it will be absolute positioned to the parent, but in this case there is no relative position parent, so it takes the browser as reference)

Changing that then you apply the code I sent you and voila! it should work:

```
#floatingCirclesG{
    position:absolute;
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    margin-left: -62px; 
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(0.6);
    -o-transform:scale(0.6);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.6);
}
```

Please check this link to understand why this works... hopes it helps
http://patosalazar.com/journal/css-snippets-awesome-one-liners/

Comment: I have tried your approaches you have provided and it still does not render the spinner in the center for FF nor in IE

Comment: can you post you code in fiddle or plunker to play with it?

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robontrix/7zqgzqhp/#&togetherjs=gjqHwcAcLh

Comment: @RobertoFlores please check my updated answer. I think I solve your issue